# How can I protect my credit card on sites where 2FA is not an option?

Tags: credit-card, multi-factor, one-time-password, paypal

I'm using Visa Express, and sometimes when I'm shopping, the store

doesn't support Verified by Visa - so that means that there is no 2FA option.

Normally when there is that option, it will force me to enter my phone number

where I will get OTP which has time experation in order to verify payment.

[image]

I called my bank and they said that I should avoid

those web shops, who doesn't support that option.

So my question here is, is there any other option to protect myself,

or is it maybe more secure to use paypal instead my credit card?

Comment: Yes... (a) Always keep an eye on your credit card statement and report suspicious transactions (b) get a second credit card with a fixed, low credit limit, and use that for any internet transactions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing you can do. Because if it's actually you using the web site, then fraud is obviously not an issue. The 2FA only helps if *someone else* is using a web site pretending to be you, and so nothing that *you* do on web sites will make any difference. You can't stop a fraudster who has got hold of your card details from using them on a web site that doesn't use 2FA.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of seeing this from the point of view of the card, look at this from the point of view of your account's money (that after all it's what matters, right?).

So, how can you protect your money in such sites? Simple solution: using a virtual credit card. Most banks offer these kind of cards that you should always have with no funds. Then when you are about to buy something, just load the exact amount so after the purchase the card is again with no funds.

Comment: "Most banks offer these kind of cards" .. Most ??  In an unscientific 5-minute survey involving Google and a few websites of major banks in various countries, I think your "most" claim leaves a lot to be desired !  Certainly none of the banks I have accounts with offer virtual cards.

Comment: @LittleCode most Spanish do, and just checked Barclays, Lloyds and Bank of America, all of them have a virtual credit card as well.

Comment: Maybe we can create an overview per country or something? This could be some useful information for people choosing a bank.

Comment: @Ayozint, well I wish I lived in Spain ! ;-)   (The food is pretty awesome in Spain too !)

Answer (score 1):

Some card issuers let you create a [virtual credit card](http://www.businessinsider.com/abine-maskme-protects-against-hackers-2014-1?IR=T). You can setup a virtual card, configure appropriate limits, then use it on an insecure site with much less risk than using your main card.

A low-tech alternative is to get a pre-paid credit card and use that whenever you're concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy at sites that are PCI DSS complaint. The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) is a proprietary information security standard and the merchants who comply with it are more secure monitored and surveyed by a qualified security assessor .

You will be able to identify these merchants by the PCI Turquoise logo in white letters at the payment page.